# Should I use String or int for nullable numeric values?

Tags: java, spring-boot, date, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to read a csv file having these fields and values:

```
// "reference"         "choice",    "startDate"
// "123",              "3",         "06.03.1987"
// "Set 1",            "1",         "11.06.1999"
// "Set 2",            "2",         "05.07.2002"
// "Set 3",            "",          "05.07.2002"
```

The `reference` field is unique and the `choice` field may be null. In this scene, for my Entity definition:

**1.** Should I use `String` for the `choice` field as it may be null (empty string) in the csv file?

**2.** Should I make the `reference` field PK or even if it is unique, I think it is better to use a `Long` id field and add `@Column(unique = true)` for the `reference` field. Is that right?

**3.** For the `startDate` field, I think I should use `LocalDate`, instead of `Date` as it is deprecated. Is that true?

Comment: I assume you are asking about mapping the fields in the CSV to the fields of database table.

Comment: Yes, I referred Entity in my Spring Data JPA. ANy idea?

Comment: @ChengThao Chico? Are you there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *1. Should I use String for the choice field as it may be null (empty string) in the csv file?*

You could parse the csv value as `String`, and use `Integer.parseInt()` before writing to the database (so that you write either a valid number, or `null` when the csv value isn't parseable).

> *2. Should I make the reference field PK or even if it is unique, I think it is better to use a Long id field and add @Column(unique = true) for the reference field. Is that right?*

There are a number of considerations for how to choose a primary key, whether uniqueness makes sense, how to handle duplicates for the unique value (fail the new addition? add a related row? update existing row, overwriting existing values?). You could make an entire post about this question.

> *3. For the startDate field, I think I should use LocalDate, instead of Date as it is deprecated. Is that true?*

Sure, [`java.time.LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) would be a good choice.

A bit pedantic, but: various *methods* on [`java.util.Date()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) have been deprecated, but `Date` itself is not deprecated. In general though, there are better choices available in the `java.time` package (like `LocalDate`).

Comment: Thanks a lot amigo, voted up. Regarding to **#2**, I mean that I think it is good idea to add an `id` field to the entity even if there is not in the csv file. By doing that, it is good idea to use this `id` field as PK and in `equals()` and `hash()` method. Is that true?

Comment: I really can't say either way if it's good to add `id` as primary key. It depends on the data itself – what it looks like, what the values mean, is a duplicate id possible, what happens if duplicate occurs, etc. It's easy to designate a certain field or value as a primary key, and enforce uniqueness, but that doesn't mean it's the right thing to do in your case.